# Subselect vs Slicer in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

If I want my results to be evaluated in the context of any tuple in MDX, *but don't want this tuple to be part of the results*, I use either of the below two options.

**1. SUBSELECT**

```
SELECT [Measures].[SomeMeasure] ON 0,
[DimName].[HierName].children ON 1
FROM
(SELECT foo.bar.&[Val] ON 0 FROM
[MyCube])
```

**2. SLICER**

```
SELECT [Measures].[SomeMeasure] ON 0,
[DimName].[HierName].children ON 1
FROM    
[MyCube]
WHERE (foo.bar.&[Val])
```

Third option that came to my mind is `EXISTS`clause, but soon I realized that it is meant for something else altogether.

So, other aspects aside, I am interested in the general ***performance*** of these queries, any benchmarks or best practices to be kept in mind and which one to go for in which circumstances.

Comment: With a subselect you can still add `foo.bar.` to rows or columns but with a where slicer this isn't possible. From the brief bit of reading I've done it seems like subselects are very good if you want to play around with visual totals e.g. in your first script the ALL member of `foo.bar.` will now be the same as the total for `foo.bar.&[Val]`. The subselect happens first and reduces the space in the cube so I imagine there is some performance gain, particularly if the outer query is complex. Have starred (and +1'd) your question Sourav as interested to see answer.

Comment: Yep, subqueries(or subselects) have a lot more to offer in terms of flexibility. But that's precisely why I want to know if they have a darker side? If not, I would prefer to ALWAYS go for them, given that they give lot more features.

Answer (score 1):

As mostly with optimizer questions, the answer is: It depends. I would say WHERE is faster in many situations, but there are cases where subselect is faster.

Optimizers are a normally not documented to each detail by vendors (even if some ore more documented than others, and Analysis Services is a typical example of an engine with a less documented optimizer). I would think they have many, many rules in their code like "if this and that, but not a third condition, then go along that route". And this constantly changes, hence any documentation would be outdated with more or less each hotfix.

As said, the situation is a bit better for many relational engines, where for SQL Server, you can at least show a plan that is more or less understandable. But even there you do not know why exactly the optimizer chose this plan and not another, and sometimes have to try several approaches to get the optimizer on another path (like using an index, ...). And a new release of SQL Server may handle things differently, hopefully better in most cases, but possibly worse in a few rare cases.

That clearly is also not a clear and documented way of writing code, but just trial and error.

**In summary:** You will have to test with your cube and your typical queries.

Anyway, in many cases, the performance difference is so small that it is not relevant.

Finally, the best documentation that is available for the Analysis Services optimizer is the old blog of one of the Analysis Services query engine developers at http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/default.aspx. This being a blog, it is not very systematic, but just a collection of some random samples of optimizer behavior with the reasons behind it.

Comment: But there has to be some rule why they behave the way they do when they do. What really goes on inside the engine? I am looking for any references which might clear the air.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti Vendors do not normally give you details of the inner workings of their optimizers, this is the case for relational engines, and much more so for Analysis Services multidimensional. I would think they have many, many rules in their code like "if this and that, but not a third condition, then go along that route". And this constantly changes, hence any documentation would be outdated with more or less each hotfix. As said, the situation is a bit better for relational engines, where for SQL Server, you can at least show a plan that is more or less understandable. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) But even there you do not know why exactly the optimizer chose this plan and not another, and sometimes have to try several approaches to get the optimizer on another path (like using an index, ...). That clearly is also not a clear and documented way of writing code, but just trial and error.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti And the best reference to some of the inner workings of the SSAS engine (at least for 2005 and 2008, but probably there was not much that changed) can be found as some fragments in Mosha's blog: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/default.aspx

Comment: @FrankPl you could move these three comments into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, If you want to cache results of your queries and improve overall throughput then slicer is better, but if you just care about single query performance then you can get better performance with subselect.

Answering the question below, 
Following information is from Chris Webb

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1fe120b-256c-425e-93a5-24278b2ab1f3/subselect-or-where-slice?forum=sqlanalysisservices
First of all, it needs to be said that subselects and the Where clause do two different things - they're not interchangeable in all circumstances, they may return different results, and sometimes one performs better, sometimes the other does, because they may result in different query plans being generated. One technique is not consistently 'better' than the other on all cubes, and any differences in performance may well change from service pack to service pack.

To answer the original question: use whichever you find gives you the best query performance and returns the results you want to see. In general I prefer the Where clause (which is *not* deprecated); the reason is that while a subselect may perform faster initially in some cases, it limits Analysis Services' ability to cache the result of calculations which means slower performance in the long term:
http://cwebbbi.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7B84B0F2C239489A!3057.entry

Comment: Do you have any references or examples which indicate the same?

Comment: Edited my answer since the reply is too long